# How to insert a string in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

When I try to insert a string in stored procedure, it is showing error message...

```
Select empcode, isnull(name, + ''0'' +) from employee
```

The above query is showing error, when I try with single quotation, then the result is same

How to insert a string in a stored procedure.

Need query help

Comment: Please make it more clear.....

Comment: What are you actually trying to "insert"? Please clarify the question better. The syntax error you get from above should be obvious, but it's not obvious what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either

```
Select empcode, isnull(name, ''0'') from employee
```

or

```
Select empcode, isnull(name, '0') from employee
```

Choose one which suits without errors.